# How to Remove Decimal in a Single Column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to convert column to row and row to column in a DataFrame.

```
      user_id    movie_id    rating
32236   1         1           5
23171   1         2           3
83307   1         3           4
62631   1         4           3
47638   1         5           3
26184   2         1           4
1333    5         1           4
172     5         2           3
54487   6         1           4
52430   7         4           5
18504   10        1           4
4617    10        4           4
44328   12        4           5
30881   13        1           3
4470    13        2           3
21009   13        4           5
39066   13        5           1
```

next I did :

```
df = ratings.pivot_table(index=['movie_id'], columns='user_id', values='rating', fill_value='').rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
df
```

this is what I got :

```
movie_id    1   2   5   6   7   10  12  13
0   1     5.0   4   4   4       4       3
1   2     3.0       3                   3
2   3     4.0                           
3   4     3.0               5   4   5   5
4   5     3.0                           1
```

The issue is the original value weren't decimals, why does the first column of the ranking(the '1' column) use decimals numbers?
And how to fix it properly(not just removing the decimals from the column, but to fix it like it's as expected as other columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is mixing numeric values with non numeric `fill_value=''`, then floats are displayed like integers:

```
df1 = ratings.pivot_table(index='movie_id', columns='user_id', values='rating', fill_value='')
print (df1)
user_id    1  2  5  6  7  10 12 13
movie_id                          
1         5.0  4  4  4     4     3
2         3.0     3              3
3         4.0                     
4         3.0           5  4  5  5
5         3.0                    1
```

---

```
print (df1.applymap(type))
user_id                1                2                5                6   \
movie_id                                                                       
1         <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>   
2         <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>   
3         <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>   
4         <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>   
5         <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>   

user_id                7                10               12               13  
movie_id                                                                      
1           <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>    <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>  
2           <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>  
3           <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  
4         <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'float'>  
5           <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>    <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
```

If use numeric `fill_value=0` it working nice:

```
df = ratings.pivot_table(index='movie_id', columns='user_id', values='rating', fill_value=0)
print (df)
user_id   1   2   5   6   7   10  12  13
movie_id                                
1          5   4   4   4   0   4   0   3
2          3   0   3   0   0   0   0   3
3          4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4          3   0   0   0   5   4   5   5
5          3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

If values is not necessary aggregate and need only pivot first convert to strings and then replace missing values:

```
ratings['rating'] = ratings['rating'].astype(str)
df = ratings.pivot(index='movie_id', columns='user_id', values='rating').fillna('')
print (df)
user_id  1  2  5  6  7  10 12 13
movie_id                        
1         5  4  4  4     4     3
2         3     3              3
3         4                     
4         3           5  4  5  5
5         3                    1
```

Comment: It works with `fill_value=0`, but it's still the same with `fillna('')` and `fillna(0)`. Is there any solution with no 0s filled?

Comment: @JerryChen - If use `pivot_table` and at least one `NaN` then all columns are converted to floats.

Comment: @JerryChen - Or if test real data then problem is aggregating by `mean`, because `pivot_table` have default `aggfunc='mean'`

Comment: Yes, the problem is involved with `pivot_table`, it's fine with the 0s though. But why is there only one column displaying float, instead of all columns? BTW, you really helped me out, thanks!

Comment: @JerryChen - Because it this columns are not missing values. All columns with not missing values are float only.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!